# Зачем нужна staging area (index) в GIT?

Tags: git, git-add, git-stash

Начал разбираться с git, попробовал писать команды, коммиты и т.д. Оценил некоторые интересные вещи. Но я так и не понял, почему я должен использовать staging area и stash? Для чего они были задуманы и как это делает жизнь разработчиков лучше?

Каков для вас типичный ежедневный цикл работы с git?

Comment: stash, насколько я знаю, нужен для кэширования сделанных изменений, когда их нельзя залить на мастер сразу. Откуда такой граватар? Я тоже такой хочу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Индекс (staging area)

Область подготовленных файлов (**staging area**) — это обычный файл, обычно хранящийся в каталоге Git, который содержит информацию о том, что должно войти в следующий коммит. Иногда его называют индексом (index), но в последнее время становится стандартом называть его областью подготовленных файлов. Область подготовленных файлов  это уже не рабочий каталог, но ещё и не коммит.

У меня типичный ежедневный цикл - 20-25 коммитов. Работаю в Netbeans

#### Команда `git stash`

Команда **git stash** нужна в основном тогда, когда Вам нужно временно спрятать текущие изменения.

> *Цитата*: Часто возникает такая ситуация, что пока вы работаете над частью своего проекта, всё находится в беспорядочном состоянии, а вам нужно переключить ветки, чтобы немного поработать над чем-то другим. Проблема в том, что вы не хотите делать коммит с наполовину доделанной работой, только для того, чтобы позже можно было вернуться в это же состояние. Ответ на эту проблему — команда git stash.

Подробнее: [6.3 Инструменты Git - Прятанье](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5)

Comment: Спасибо за прояснение. А как вы считаете, начинающему все же лучше будет книга Pro Git или Version Control with Git: Powerful tools and techniques for collaborative software development от O'Reilly. Просто кто-то сказал мне, что в той книге, на которую вы только что ссылались(Pro Git), есть ошибки. Насколько это правда?

Comment: @Venje Я читал эту книгу. К тому моменту, как вы начнёте находить там ошибки (я лично не нашёл), Ваш уровень будет таков, что Вам Version Control with Git мало чем поможет.

Comment: «в последнее время становится стандартом называть его областью подготовленных файлов» — не могли бы вы уточнить, в чем это проявляется? В документации такой термин используется или в рабочем общении? Я вполне верю, но сам впервые встречаю такое.

Comment: Кстати, добавил ваш вопрос в описание метки: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/git-add/info