# Как правильно коммитить файлы, целый каталог, чтобы не коммитились все за раз

Tags: git

К примеру я сделал `git add .` после чего все файлы добавились, и как мне теперь сделать коммиты для определенных файлов? Я хочу, чтобы были коммиты только для определенный файлов, а для остальных коммит но пустой. Так получилось, что я запушил все файлы одним коммитом. И теперь все файлы под коммитом "Fix slide-menu".

Comment: Не делать `git add .` а делать `git add путь/к/нужному.файлу`

Comment: `git add -p`, `git add -i`, `git reset HEAD`, .... Тут можно много написать, продуктивнее будет пройти урок по гиту, в интернете их много. Вам нужно изучить основные команды и понять, что такое stage область для начала.

Comment: Благодарю за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы не повторяться о том, что же такое индекс:

- [Зачем нужна staging area (index) в GIT?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/153301/178576)
- [Git index предназначение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/402953/178576)
- [Что значит индексация в контексте Git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1207143/178576)

теперь собственно вопрос:

> как правильно коммитить файлы …, чтобы не коммитились все за раз?

команда *commit* (без опции `-a`, конечно) формирует коммит из содержимого индекса (staging area). а в индекс файлы (новые либо изменённые) добавляются при помощи команды *add*.

отсюда логически следует:

- что добавили в индекс, то в коммит и попадёт.
- чтобы в коммит не попало «всё подряд», надо и добавлять **выборочно**.

можно указать конкретный файл, или целый каталог (добавлен будет, естественно, не каталог, а содержащиеся в нём файлы, рекурсивно). отдельными командами *add* или целой пачкой. примеры:

```
$ git add файл
$ git add путь/к/файлу
$ git add каталог/с/файлами
$ git add файл1 путь/к/файлу2 каталог/с/файлами ...
```

не бойтесь продублировать команды — файл добавится только один раз, сколько бы раз вы его не упомянули в командах *add*.

можно использовать шаблоны оболочки: `*` — вместо любого количества символов, `?` — вместо одного символа. текущий каталог, как обычно, можно указать точкой: `.`

посмотреть, какие файлы добавлены в индекс, можно, например, командой *status*:

```
$ git status
```

правда, эта команда показывает и другую информацию (бывает, много), и чтобы видеть **только** добавленные в индекс файлы, можно использовать:

```
$ git diff --name-only --cached
```

убрать файл из индекса можно командой *rm* с опцией `--cached`. указать можно и один файл, и много файлов. можно указать и каталог, чтобы исключить файлы рекурсивно. тогда надо будет добавить ещё и опцию `-r`:

```
$ git rm --cached файл
$ git rm --cached путь/к/файлу
$ git rm --cached -r каталог/с/файлами
$ git rm --cached -r файл1 путь/к/файлу2 каталог/с/файлами ...
```

как и в случае с командой *add*, можно использовать шаблоны оболочки.

Comment: Благодарю за столь подробный ответ. Еще раз спасибо.